# Will the Genie be blue?

Tags: disney, aladdin-2019

I  noticed the new cover of Entertainment Weekly, which features a cover of the actors to be in the new live-action *Aladdin*.

[image]

With Will Smith slated to be the Genie, he decidedly does not look like the Genie from the original animated feature.

Will the Genie be a blue entity in the new film or will he just be a regular looking human with magic powers?

Comment: He's a fan of [Shazzan](https://www.flickr.com/photos/33158682@N06/4446729620) maybe

Comment: Wait, they're doing a live-action *Aladdin* remake now?  \*facepalm\*  Why?  Just... why?

Comment: @MasonWheeler There is a Jungle Book, Cinderella, Beauty and the Beast, Dumbo, The Lion King, and I know am forgetting something else either already release or to be released. I think the objective is to get most of the high grossing classics...

Comment: Yeah, and the *Jungle Book* and *Beauty and the Beast* ones were both awful, and *Dumbo* doesn't look like it'll be any better from what I've seen so far, so why are they pushing for even more?

Comment: @BruceWayne because those are *Pixar*... while these are all original Disney animations.

Comment: @Mason Wheeler - Dumbo?  WHY?????????

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Why on earth would Disney make more movies? There’s literally no way to figure it out. On an entirely unrelated note, *Jungle Book* [made $966 million](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=junglebook2015.htm) at the box office; *Beauty and the Beast* [made $1,263 million](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=beautyandthebeast2017.htm).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite those numbers make me sad.  Especially the *Beauty and the Beast* one, because that isn't just a bad movie, it's an *actively harmful* one. The message it teaches is that a girl who finds herself in an abusive relationship, (let's be honest; the Beast's treatment of her has "abuse" written all over it,) she can fix things by staying with him and loving him enough to make him change. In the real world, the way that story ends is with the woman battered or dead. Showing this movie to its target audience (impressionable young girls) is likely to literally end with some of them dying!

Comment: @MasonWheeler: yeah but it also has a singing teapot, so that's nice.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

### The genie will be (mostly) blue and CGI.

Straight from the horse's mouth:

> BAM!! First look at the Genie ‍♂️, Princess Jasmine, and #Aladdin! Check Me Rockin’ the Top Knot Ponytail Vibes in @entertainmentweekly  (and yes, I’m gonna be BLUE! :-) This is how the Genie is in Human / Disguise Form. My character will be CGI most of the movie.)
>
> <sub>-- **Will Smith**, the actor himself, on [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/p/BrkhMBcBifX/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link)</sub>

Comment: https://twitter.com/sheilaslalaland/status/1075394723613790208/photo/1?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1075394723613790208&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bustle.com%2Fp%2Fwill-smiths-genie-in-aladdin-will-be-blue-so-consider-your-wish-fulfilled-15548128

Comment: What a weird decision to show him in only in human form, making people think that's what's going to happen. I know a lot of people who saw that and decided it was a sign that the movie was crap and decided not to go see it.

Comment: @trlkly: I can think of a few explanations: 1) EW doesn't care about Disney's bottom line and went with the photo that would sell magazines, 2) the CGI form is less recognizable as Will Smith, 3) the CGI might not be finalized yet, 4) Disney is saving the CGI form for a teaser trailer, 5) the people who decide not to see it on the basis of this cover were not going to like the movie in the first place.

Comment: @Kevin - I would have assumed that Disney has some control in the costumes/characters being photographed by/for EW, and they were aware and okay with the non-Blue Genie photo...I'd be surprised if EW was allowed to shoot any photos they wanted, and publish them without Disney's "Okay" first.

Comment: Well, I never said it was a *good* explanation...

Comment: Well, I'm not going to see it on the basis that I dislike being shaken by the ankles in the search for loose change.

Comment: @trlkly: “ I know a lot of people who saw that and decided it was a sign that the movie was crap and decided not to go see it.” I’m going to go out on a massive limb and suggest that maybe, just maybe, some of those people might see a subsequent poster or trailer or magazine cover featuring a blue genie, and change their minds.

Answer (score 14):

The director, Guy Ritchie, indicated in [an interview with Entertainment Weekly](https://ew.com/movies/2018/12/19/aladdin-first-look-ew-cover-story/) that the genie will appear in at least some parts of the movie in a form closer to the original.

> The final version of Will Smith’s Genie in his blue floating lamp form isn’t quite finished — the film is due in theaters on May 24, 2019 — but Ritchie gives EW a tease of what he’ll look like. “I wanted a muscular 1970s dad,” the director says. “He was big enough to feel like a force — not so muscular that he looked like he was counting his calories, but formidable enough to look like you knew when he was in the room.” When Aladdin first stumbles across the lamp in the Cave of Wonders, a big cerulean cloud whooshes out of the spout, forming into Smith’s goateed Genie, complete with a topknot.